# Random walk with variable transition probabilities

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, markov-chains, random-walk

Suppose we are dealing with a discrete 1D random walk. At each point, we have different probabilities of making step to the left or to the right.

```
--------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
Points        | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
--------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
P(move right) |...|0.3|0.5|0.7|0.4|0.8|0.9|...|
--------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
P(move left)  |...|0.7|0.5|0.3|0.6|0.2|0.1|...|
--------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

For example, the probability to get from point 3 to point 4 is 0.7, and the probability to get from same point 3 to 2 is 0.3.

In other words, it is like a Markov chain: states are points; transitions are possible only between neighboring states; all transition probabilities are known.

Suppose the motion begins at point 3. How can we calculate the probability that we will get to point 7 before we get to point 0?

Comment: Greetings! What have you tried on this problem? Would you know how to solve it if all the transition probabilities were 0.5? What tactics are you familiar with?

Comment: With equiprobable steps left and right, the probability of reaching a point at a distance R steps to the right (not reaching a point L steps left) will be L/(L+R). As you can see, I'm not very willing to use mathematical notation, since my experience is more algorithmic than mathematical. And whereas simple random walks with constant probabilities are often described in the literature with understandable examples, I have no idea how to approach this issue when the transition probabilities are different at each point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book "Random Walks and Electric Networks" has some useful examples that should be of assistance:

https://math.dartmouth.edu/~doyle/docs/walks/walks.pdf

In particular, I'll point you to section 1.2.6 -- particularly, the part starting with, "As a second example," on the top of page 26. The gist is that you'll set up a $8 \times 8$ matrix whose $(i, j)$ entry is the probability of going from $i$ to $j$ -- e.g. the $(3, 4)$ entry would be $0.7$ per what you've written above. Most of the entries will be $0$, including all entries along the diagonal (except for the $(0,0)$ and $(7, 7)$ entries, which will be $1$ since they are your absorbing states).

After you have this matrix, your task is to reordering the states so that the absorbing states are in the upper left and your transition matrix has the canonical form
$$M = \left( \begin{array}{cc} I_2 & 0 \\ R & Q \end{array} \right)$$ where in your case, $I_2$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix, the $0$ is a $2 \times 6$ block of $0$ entries, $R$ is a $6 \times 2$ block matrix consisting of the probabilities of each state transitioning into one of the absorbing states, and $Q$ is a $6 \times 6$ matrix with transition probabilities for the non-absorbing states. The computation $(I_6 - Q)^{-1}R$ will then give you the absorption probabilities you're looking for.

I highly recommend the above link, as it explains what I just described in much better detail and includes some fully worked-out examples.

Comment: I successfully calculated all the probabilities by the proposed method and tested them empirically. Many thanks for the link and clear explanations.